# Folder structure for TensorFlow image segmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation) to do image segmentation with tensorflow. However, I want to make my own data for this. What should my folder structure be if I'm trying to stay consistent with the tutorial? Currently, I have the following:

```
path/to/image
  train/
    image/
      1.png
      ...
    segmentation_mask/
      1.jpg
  test/
    image/
      6.png
      ...
    segmentation_mask/
      6.jpg
      ...
```

I'm trying to read the dataset using `tf.data_folder.ImageFolder("path/to/image")` and then `.as_dataset()` to convert it to be a dataset. However, this raises errors throughout the rest of the program. So, how to I structure my folders and how do I load the dataset in properly so there would not be any more errors?

Answer (score 1):

To load your dataset properly and avoid errors, you need to structure your folders as follows:

```
path/to/image/
  train/
    images/
      1.png
      2.png
      3.png
      ...
    masks/
      1.png
      2.png
      3.png
  test/
    images/
      6.png
      7.png
      8.png
    masks/
      6.png
      7.png
      8.png
```

Make sure that your image files and corresponding segmentation mask files have the same names and are placed in their respective folders. For example, 1.png in the train/images folder should have its corresponding mask 1.png in the train/masks folder.

To load the dataset using tf.data.Dataset.from_folder(), you can do the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the paths to the train and test directories
train_path = "path/to/image/train"
test_path = "path/to/image/test"

# Define the image and mask subdirectories
image_dir = "images"
mask_dir = "masks"

# Load the train dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_folder(
    train_path,
    image_size=(height, width),  # Set the desired image size
    seed=123,  # Set a seed for reproducibility (optional)
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode=None,  # No labels as we are loading masks
    image_folder=image_dir,
    mask_folder=mask_dir,
    interpolation="nearest"  # Set the interpolation method for resizing (optional)
)

# Load the test dataset
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_folder(
    test_path,
    image_size=(height, width),  # Set the desired image size
    seed=123,  # Set a seed for reproducibility (optional)
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode=None,  # No labels as we are loading masks
    image_folder=image_dir,
    mask_folder=mask_dir,
    interpolation="nearest"  # Set the interpolation method for resizing (optional)
)
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Can  I change my `.jpg`s to `.png`s and have them work fine?

Comment: I got a `AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'from_folder'`